# Запрос geo_grid в .net Nest

Tags: elasticsearch

Если в Elasticsearch .Net Nest вот такой запрос

```
"query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
```

можно написать так:

```
SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest(index)
{
  Query = new MatchAllQuery()
};
```

то как в Nest написать такой запрос:

```
{
  "query": {
    "geo_grid" :{
      "coordinates" : {
        "geohash" : "u1yg84u"
      }
    }
  }
}
```